# Lubuntu upgrade stops USB from working

Tags: usb, updates, lubuntu

I have a Wintel Box W8 Pro small computer I want to use to evaluate Lubuntu.

I installed Lubuntu and it was working well then an upgrade was required. It downloaded 240 updates on Friday 17 July Brisbane time and I can only say it included the xxx-40 Linux update.

The USB ports now do not work and I cannot use the keyboard or mouse so the PC is now effectively bricked.

Is there a way to access the PC to reinstall the OS or apply any patch.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry I was so vague but I can't access the PC so it is hard to be definitive.

Comment: I assume the upgrade is the same as on another PC i did  and that has Linux 5.4.0-40-generic (x86_64). Version is #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020. Library GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu) 2.31. Distribution Ubunto 20.04 LTS. The original download was from Friday 17 July, whatever version that was.

Comment: Sorry to be so vague. The PC is inaccessible without USB ports. The original download was on Friday 17 July. The upgrade happened same day and downloaded 240 updates. The end result was Linux 5.4.0-40-generic (x86_64), version #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020, library GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9) 2.31.

Comment: I don't know what happened there. I didn't see my first reply so I redid it but then the first showed up. ??. When I talk about the original download I do mean the one that was on the download site at about midday on Friday 17 July. I have found the original USB boot stick so if you need to know the details of the original download I imagine they are in there somewhere, if you can tell me where to look.

Comment: Yes it was the 20.04 LTS distribution as I said originally. I downloaded it from the Ubuntu web site.

Comment: I missed that sorry, when you add additional detail, please put it in your question (*you can edit your own questions*) as it allows greater formatting and is thus easier to read, which is useful to you as there is more chance others will read & step in and help (not everyone reads comments). I had a quick scan of launchpad & didn't see any concrete bugs thus any solutions (what I was actually looking for).  Are you able to just boot/use another kernel, ie. selecting from `grub`via *Advanced options* (usually 2 or more kernel options exist for this purpose, ie. regressions).

Comment: Thanks. I can't access the PC. There is no k/board / mouse port and no USB.

Comment: `grub` is a boot loader and is run before Ubuntu/Lubuntu, or the linux kernel has started loading (it's installed by Ubuntu yes, but it's not part of Ubuntu specifically; it's a GNU tool used to boot x86/amd64 & some architectures, other boot loaders are used for other architectures). So what you're saying is it doesn't relate to the 5.4.0-40 at all. At that point in the boot process, the BIOS/setup of the machine is controlling keyboard, (not Ubuntu/Lubuntu as it needs to be loaded before it can control things).  Did you try?

Comment: The initial install of 20.04 LTS was working fine until the upgrades, so the BIOS settings were obviously OK. Thanks for the tutorial as well. I am new to Linux but 34 years with Win and Mac.

Comment: Maybe you're not seeing `grub` or the pre-boot selection process (as it's so early & controlled mostly by your firmware; it's somewhat machine specific how it appears). It may require a key (ESC) to be pressed to appear; which will allow you to boot older kernels (and I bet including the install kernel). If you see the `plymouth` (dots, wallpaper & dots to hide posix boot messages as users find them scary; an error at finding no restore file is expected if you didn't hibernate for example) it's too late. ESC needs to be pressed early, before linux/kernel/Ubuntu has loaded so can be missed